# VB.NET Sqlclient connection hangs forever

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a tool that run a query on a SQL2005 server.
It always worked so the code is ok, but now it hangs everytime it runs the fill method:

```
Dim cn As SqlClient.SqlConnection

cn = New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=SERVERNAME;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=DOCUMENTS")

Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Invoices"
Dim da As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql, cn)
ds.Clear()
da.Fill(ds)
```

The last line is where it hangs.
I get no error, no exception, no message, nothing, simply it stay there forever!
I also tried inserting a small timeout, same result.

I also tried this:

```
Dim cn As SqlClient.SqlConnection
cn = New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=SERVERNAME;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=DOCUMENTS")
cn.Open()
```

as soon as Open is run, it hangs the same way.

Interesting is that if I open this program on a different pc (VS2008 too) it works perfectly (so it's not an issue of timeout or the query too long to execute)

So the issue seems something related to my machine.
Maybe .net framework corrupted? sqlclient corrupted? I tried reinstalling vs2008, tried to reinstall the frameworks on this machine with no success.

I had SQL2012 management installed, I tried uninstalling it, never know, nothing.

It is not the firewall because I tried disabling it.
Another interesting point: the connection to the same SQL server is working from my machine using MS Access, SQL manager, from UDL files, from VS2008 server explorer and so on.

It seems there is something about **SQLCLIENT** not working on this machine but I don't know what to check

thanks

**[EDIT]**
The UDL file is working only using OLEDB provider! if I try "SQL Native client" or "SQL Server native client 10.0" it hangs the same way... definitly the problem is with sqlclient

Comment: Is the SQL server up and running? The service in "services.msc"? Does you account have access as you're using SSPI security

Comment: as specified in the descrition, the same code is working fine from another pc (using the same AD Account), so yes, the sql service is running and the account has access

Comment: It's a long shot, but are you certain that both PC have the exact same version of .NET installed and the same framework updates if any?

Comment: no, for sure they don't have it, to be more specific, the other machine is a virtual machine with windows 2008 server, my pc is a windows7 64bit.. but I can add: this tool is run from other machines like W7 32bit and maybe an XP and always working, so it's something on my pc. I could reinstall my machine but I'd prefer to understand what's the source of the problem

Comment: Have you tried running Sql Profiler just to know if the query ever makes it to the server at all? Knowing this could get you closer to an answer.

Comment: as you can notice in the description and in the EDIT the problem is before the query applies

Comment: From what you've said, sounds like a reinstall of SQL server would be the easiest way, but appreciate the pain involved! Have you checked in SQL Server Configuration Manager that TCP/IP is enabled? And shared memory?

Comment: For sure is not a problem of SQL server as it's working from other PC, something is messed up on my client, the server is ok for sure